# Can't install Homebrew: Can't find the certificate

Tags: ssh, installation, git, ssl, homebrew

Attempted to install Homebrew with the following command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Received this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': SSL: Can't find the certificate "kgreenwood" and its private key in the Keychain.

Attempted to work on something else, discovered that I couldn't clone from git with HTTPS anymore.  I generated an SSH keypair (disclaimer: I know almost nothing about certificates) and can now clone using SSH URLs.

I assume the issue is that the Homebrew installation command uses an HTTPS url.  Is there some way I can force it to use SSH instead?  I've tried "untar anywhere" alternative solution in their guide (typing `mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew` in `/usr/local`) but I keep getting:

> brew: command not found

Comment: Try building it from source by adding the `--build-from-source` flag when calling `brew install`.

Comment: Regarding the `brew: command not found` error you have to add `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH. In your `~/.bashrc` add the following: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ssh instead, as always on github.

clone it into any location.

```
git clone git@github.com:Homebrew/homebrew
```

then adapt PATH. insert into .bashrc

```
export PATH=/path/to/homebrew-dir/bin:$PATH
```

then, do a `brew update` and `brew doctor`.

Comment: Regarding the “any location” part it’s always better to clone it in `/usr/local`. Homebrew will work if it’s installed in another place but some formulae won’t be available as bottles (= pre-compiled binaries).

Comment: Oh.... yes, I missed that

Comment: Wow of course.  I was making that way harder than it had to be.  I convinced myself that because I didn't know what "tarball" or "ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL etc" meant that it must have been more complicated than just cloning it from github.  I originally had export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" in my .bash_profile.  Just tried putting it in .bashrc but am still getting brew: command not found.  Does the order matter?  I have a few other things in there from RVM and Heroku Toolbelt.

Comment: if you use `mdfind -name brew`, what is the output? I don't think it's `/usr/local/bin`. more like `/usr/local/homebrew/bin` but you have to try.

Comment: ps: tarball is a tar bundles archive (mostly `.tar.gz` the `curl etc...` inside the brackets downloades an install script and `ruby -e` executes it. but that is one of the reasons why I like homebrew more than MacPorts. you can simply clone a git repo and fix path. `brew update` does not much more than save changes and `git pull`

Comment: `mdfind -name brew` gives me the following output:
`/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-tap.md
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-failed-jenkins.png
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-failed-pr.png
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-failed-test.png
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-for-core-contributors-block.png
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-for-core-contributors-console.png
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-for-core-contributors-tabs.png`
...

Comment: `/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-for-core-contributors-trigger.png
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-passed-jenkins.png
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-passed-pr.png
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-triggered-pr.png
/usr/local/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/The-brew-command.md
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/Querying-Brew.md`
...

Comment: `/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/Brew-Test-Bot.md
/usr/local/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew/Brew-Test-Bot-For-Core-Contributors.md
/usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew
/usr/local/homebrew/Library/brew.rb
/usr/local/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1.md
/usr/local/homebrew/Library/Formula/brew-pip.rb
/usr/local/homebrew/Library/Formula/brew-gem.rb
/usr/local/homebrew/Library/Contributions/brew_zsh_completion.zsh
/usr/local/homebrew/Library/Contributions/brew_bash_completion.sh
/Applications/rubystack-2.0.0-29/rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/osx_brew`

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42088895/55075), most likely it's misconfiguration of your `~/.gitconfig`.

Check for `sslCert` and `sslVerify` options and adjust the settings accordingly or remove them.